# Xprinter q260nl OPOS doesn't print any Russian characters

Tags: c#, printers, opos

I have an issue with printing Russian symbols through XPrinter q260nl, it prints question marks.

I am using OPOS Drivers and my code in C# UWP with framework POS for .NET Windows 10 version is 1809. I tried to print through Microsoft POS Tester app which comes with POS for .NET.

Printer is connected through USB. Printer prints fine, but English letters only.

```
ReceiptPrintJob job = claimedPrinter.Receipt.CreateJob();  
job.PrintLine(“Я русский”);

await job.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: As I can see [here](http://poskeytech.com/html/80mm-Series/67.html) your printer handles only PC866 encoding (DOS), but `Я русский` - is unicode sequence. If you can print a `byte[]` - you may use something like this: `Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"), Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Россия - священная наша держава"))`

Comment: @vasily.sib But UWP accepts only ANSI ASCII UTF16LE

Comment: Yap, that's why you need to convert it from _"ANSI ASCII UTF16LE"_ (which is `Encoding.Unicode`) to _"PC866 "_ (which is `Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866")`)

Comment: @vasily.sib as I can print only strings my code is: job.PrintLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866").GetBytes("я русский"))); and it gives me an error System.ArgumentException: "Argument_EncodingNotSupported, cp866. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485"

Comment: can you test this: `var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866").GetBytes("Я русский"); var str = new string(bytes.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray()); job.PrintLine(str);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether 866 is included in the value of `PosPrinter.SupportedCharacterSets` Property.

If 866 is not included, you will not be able to print Russian characters.
If the value contains 866, try setting `ClaimedPosPrinter.CharacterSet` Property to 866 before CreateJob().

If you can not print in the above, please change all the OS region and language settings for Russia.
Especially, setting of "Language of non-Unicode Programs" is important.

Comment: I don't have 866 code in PosPrinter.SupportedCharacterSets, is there any way to include that or other solution for that?

Comment: @Akbar Shamsutdinov, In that case, please abandon API such as OPOS/POS for .NET/Windows.Devices.PointOfService and send the ESC/POS control sequence data directly using the serial port.